# Pydantic 2.0 multiple Basemodel classes - how to handle class dependencies

Tags: python, python-typing, pydantic

How can I make my other classes optional in pydantic 2.0? When I have data I dont get an error, however, when I send a null value I get a ValidationError Field Required type=missing error.

For Example, I could do ***profile: Optional[dict[str, str]] = None in User*** and that works but it defeats the point of using **class (Profile)**

```
from typing import Optional, Dict

class User(BaseModel):
    id: str
    username: str
    password: str
    connections: Optional[Connections]     <---- not working returning ValdiationError if null value sent
    profile: Optional[Profile]             <---- not working returning ValdiationError if null value sent

class Profile(BaseModel):
    id: str
    profile_id: str
    details: str
    

class Connections(BaseModel):
     connection_id: str
     connection_count: int
     connection_names: Dict[str, str]
```

I'm new to the updates in pydnatic so any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to move from custom classes, You can have default values set on None and still use your models:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional, Dict           

class Profile(BaseModel):
    id: str
    profile_id: str
    details: str
    

class Connections(BaseModel):
     connection_id: str
     connection_count: int
     connection_names: Dict[str, str]
        
class User(BaseModel):
    id: str
    username: str
    password: str
    connections: Optional[Connections] = None  
    profile: Optional[Profile] = None
```

I agree that it is rather unfortunate that even with Optional type pydantic cannot handle it without default value, but i think it is not a problem nor code smell in any case.

Comment: thanks for the response. I doing this for profile - profile: Optional[Profile] = None and I received a validation error and  the response was  -> Field Required [type=missing, input_value={'dictexample': '24', 'dictexample': '2'}, input_type=dict]

Comment: Please provide code after changes and how example of usage

Comment: oh my goodness it was a naming conflict. In my data I had Connections: Optional[Connections] = None and after changing class Connections to class ProfileConnections it fixed the issue.  Optional[ProfileConnections ] = None works!

Comment: How can I do in 2 to create the entire substructer like in pydantic v1:
`something: Optional[Somthing] = Field(default_factory=Something)`
where Something is something is: ```class Something(BaseModel):   id: int | None``` ?